# Adding space between containers in a listview

Tags: flutter, dart

i'm new to flutter and i'm trying to add some space between containers in a listview, literally tried everything but failed at it, I want to divide them containers for a better visualization of the items inside of the list, thanks in advance!

Code:

```
body: Column(
  children: <Widget>[
    Expanded(
      child: ListView.builder(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
        itemCount: 6,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return Row(
            children: [
              SizedBox(
                width: 70,
                child: AspectRatio(
                  aspectRatio: 0.88,
                  child: Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(22),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Color(0xFFF5F6F9),
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                    ),
                    child: Image.asset(
                      'assets/syringe.png',
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(width: 20),
              Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Text(
                    "Type d'analyse",
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 16),
                    maxLines: 2,
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 10),
                  Text.rich(
                    TextSpan(
                      text: "Date: ",
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                          color: kPrimaryColor),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          );
        },
      ),
    )
  ],
),
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `ListView.separated` instead of `ListView.builder`

It works exactly the same but with the added `separatorBuilder` parameter. Which could be something like

```
  separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) => const Divider()
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the `Row` in a `Container` and set `margin` like so:

```
body: Column(
  children: <Widget>[
    Expanded(
      child: ListView.builder(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
        itemCount: 6,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10),
            child: Row(
            children: [
              SizedBox(
                width: 70,
                child: AspectRatio(
                  aspectRatio: 0.88,
                  child: Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(22),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Color(0xFFF5F6F9),
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                    ),
                    child: Image.asset(
                      'assets/syringe.png',
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(width: 20),
              Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Text(
                    "Type d'analyse",
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 16),
                    maxLines: 2,
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 10),
                  Text.rich(
                    TextSpan(
                      text: "Date: ",
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                          color: kPrimaryColor),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ],
         ),
          );
        },
      ),
    )
  ],
),
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use separator builder or you can wrap list items with padding widget.

```
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            child: ListView.separated(
              separatorBuilder: (context, index) => SizedBox(height: 10,),
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
              itemCount: 6,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: Row(
                    children: [
                      SizedBox(
                        width: 70,
                        child: AspectRatio(
                          aspectRatio: 0.88,
                          child: Container(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.all(22),
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              color: Color(0xFFF5F6F9),
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                            ),
                            child: Image.asset(
                              'assets/syringe.png',
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(width: 20),
                      Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: [
                          Text(
                            "Type d'analyse",
                            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 16),
                            maxLines: 2,
                          ),
                          SizedBox(height: 10),
                          Text.rich(
                            TextSpan(
                              text: "Date: ",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                                  color: Colors.white),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
```